# Print current best parameters during RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn

While doing a `RandomizedSearchCV` loop and waiting for it to finish, is it possible to have the *current best* combination of parameters being printed on screen? (and not just the last tried one?)

This is useful if, say, you have set a high number of steps and don't want to wait for it to finish before you can check `best_params_`

Comment: Did you try `verbose=1`?

Comment: No, currently the best candidates are found after all the runs are completed. So you cannot do it with inbuilt code. You can however change the code to do so. Start [here for `RandomizedSearchCV`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L695). Or you can parse the output from `verbose` to maintain your own best params outside of sklearn code.